# How to Loop Array Column in Dataframe and Join with Another Dataframe in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have two Dataframes -

**dataframe_1**

```
| some_id                                  |
|------------------------------------------|
|["23815", "23824", "36978", "23824", "81"]|
|["37551", "36091", "81"]                  |
|----------------------------------------- |

    
    
    **dataframe_2**


|--------------------------------------------------------------|    
|some_id|cor_name |propertiesMap                               |
|-------|-------- |--------------------------------------------|
|23815  |Mango    |{cor_name  -> Mango, _value -> 18912}       |
|23824  |Mango    |{cor_name  -> Mango, _value -> 52882}       |
|23824  |Mango    |{cor_name   -> Mango, _value -> 29014}      |
|23811  |Apple    |{qual_name -> Apple, _value -> E7063}       |
|-------|-------- |--------------------------------------------|
```

Note -  I am not able to Join between 'some_id' from dataframe_1, because this is array column. I want to get all columns from dataframe_2 matching some_id. I tried to iterate over every row , and then iterate over array elements.

Tried :

```
df = < some select query >
df_extra = (df.select("some_id","cor_name",df.propertiesMap.getItem("_value")))
df_Lineage = spark.sql("""select HLineage from someTable""")

for row in df_Lineage ():
    lis_1 = list(row)
    for element in lis_1:
      df_extra = ( df_extra.filter("terr_id").contains(element[0])
                 ) ## I want to filter the second dataframe values for each element of each row
      display(df_extra)
```

Expected Result

| some_id | cor_name | propertiesMap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23815 | Mango | {cor_name -> Mango, _value -> 18912} |
| ------- | --------- | ---------------------------------------- |

Comment: Could you add your expected result and your current attempted code?

Comment: yes Added. I have to traverse through all eleement in the list and get the propertiesMap for those soem_id.

Comment: could you also add expected result?

Comment: Ok, added. at this stage, only one filtered value will give me a way.

Comment: hmm, it is not clear. You mentioned you want to join dataframe but expected result is just filtered(only has dataframe_2 rows).

Comment: I meant to say, if I can join with the first element of that array list, with someid of second dataframe, it will also solve the problem. Actually, I tried several ways, now I am not even sure, which should be the good option, join or filter, or some other thing. Only dataframe_2 rows will give the values, that will work for me.

Comment: Try showing what is your desired outcome(not your output that you want to expect from your current code) or explain what is your end goal.

Comment: ok, I have edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter `dataframe_2` based on the existence in the array in `dataframe_1`, you can use the conditional inner(default) JOIN and your condition is [array_contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_contains.html).

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

dataframe_2 = (dataframe_2.join(dataframe_1,
                                on=(F.array_contains(dataframe_1.id, dataframe_2.id)))
               .drop(dataframe_1.id)
)
```

Result:

```
+-------+--------+--------------------+
|some_id|cor_name|       propertiesMap|
+-------+--------+--------------------+
|  23815|   Mango|{cor_name  -> Man...|
|  23824|   Mango|{cor_name  -> Man...|
|  23824|   Mango|{cor_name   -> Ma...|
+-------+--------+--------------------+
```